# How I solve the Error 401 Twitter API in R?

Tags: api, twitter, rtweet

I was performing a tweet analysis using the rtweet package in R. But when downloading the tweets search_tweets() the  the following error occurs:

Error: Twitter API failed [401]. Check error message at https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting

- Could not authenticate you. (32)
  In addition: Warning message:
  Could not authenticate you. (32)

I have already performed the authentication again with the command

```
auth_setup_default()
```

and

```
 auth_as()
```

But the same error keeps happening

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question of a similar question, [read my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75973152/2886003). The default authentication provided by rtweet was suspended. I'm the maintainer of the package.