# I can't use "rtweet" package in R

Tags: r, api, twitter, tweets, rtweet

I am trying to setup the default authentication mechanism of  the "rtweet" package. But i got this error:
"**Error in httr::init_oauth1.0(endpoint, app, permission = permission, is_interactive = is_interactive,  : Unauthorized (HTTP 401).**"

This is the code i have been using and the outputs that i have:

```
rtweet::auth_setup_default()
```

> Error in httr::init_oauth1.0(endpoint, app, permission = permission, is_interactive = is_interactive,  :
> Unauthorized (HTTP 401).

```
auth_setup_default()
```

> Error in httr::init_oauth1.0(endpoint, app, permission = permission, is_interactive = is_interactive,  :
> Unauthorized (HTTP 401).

```
auth_has_default()
```

> [1] FALSE

I try to install from different sources the "rtweet" package. For example :

```
remotes::install_github("ropensci/rtweet")
install.packages("rtweet", repos = 'https://ropensci.r-universe.dev')
install.packages("rtweet")
```

I have this version of the package:

```
packageVersion("rtweet")
```

> [1] ‘1.2.0’

But i still have the same problem. Can somebody help me, please

Comment: https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/756#issuecomment-1497464678
This issue thread on the package's github repo may help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the maintainer of the library. As [answered in the comments and linked](https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/756#issuecomment-1497464678), the default authentication used until now was suspended. You'll need to use your own credentials and pay if you want to collect data from Twitter.